# getting relationships when cypher when querying for shortestPath

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-java-api

I am trying to find the shortest Path between two nodes and I would like to get the relationships(start node, end node and type) so I could generate a Subgraph in Java.

I am using this cypher :

`MATCH (nodeA),(nodeB), p = shortestPath((nodeA)-[*..15]-(nodeB))
WHERE ID(nodeA) = 1332076 AND ID(nodeB) = 1459451 
UNWIND nodes(p) as n
UNWIND relationships(p) as r
RETURN collect(distinct { id : id(n), labels : labels(n), data: n}) as nodes, collect(distinct r) as relationships`

My problem is the relationships are returned in a format that I don't understand. Like this :

`{
  "TFFamily": "MADS",
  "Category": "DIRECT",
  "PubMedID": "UNKNOWN",
  "Reference": "NA",
  "Interaction": "UNCONFIRMED",
  "TargetType": "AT2G36590",
  "Confirmation": "NO",
  "isTF": "AT2G36590"
}
{
  "HIT_END": "104",
  "BLAST_alignement_length": "52",
  "BLAST_evalue": "4.00E-27",
  "HIT_START": "53",
  "BLAST_percentage_identity": "82.69",
  "percentage_match": "43.7",
  "QUERY_START": "58",
  "clusterid": "CLUSTER_5713",
  "QUERY_END": "109",
  "BLAST_mismatches": "9",
  "BLAST_nrofgaps": "0"}`

what is exactly relationship(p)?
Is there a way to get the startId, the endId and the type?

Thanks

EDIT :

Possible solution :

Not sure if this is the best option but I found there are **startNode(r) and endNode(r)**

```
" MATCH (nodeA),(nodeB), p = shortestPath((nodeA)-[%s*..%s]-(nodeB))" + //
                " WHERE ID(nodeA) = {1} AND ID(nodeB) = {2} " +  //
                " UNWIND nodes(p) as n" + //
                " UNWIND relationships(p) as r" + //
                " RETURN COLLECT(distinct { id : id(n), labels : labels(n), data: n}) as nodes, " + //
                " COLLECT(distinct { relationshipId : ID(r), startId : ID(startNode(r)), labels : type(r) , endId: ID(endNode(r))}) as edges"; //
```

Comment: First, here is all the neo4j [functions](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/functions/). Also, can you share what your data looks like?

Comment: if you check https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-refcard/current/ you can find startNode(a_relationship) and endNode(a_relationship) to find start and end node of the relationship and type(a_relationship) for the relationship type

Comment: Hey Tomaž thanks for replying. Indeed that's what I did. I have made an EDIT to my original post